# Standard FTP Login java class

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

Is there a defined standard class for dealing with FTP login data? Something that already handles storing, sharing? Since I am relatively new to this, maybe someone else gave this topic already a thorough thinking. Could not find anything in Apache Commons so far...
For now I use my own class, it is not very fulfilling:

```
public class FTPLogin {

    String hostaddress;
    int port;
    String name;
    String password;

    public FTPLogin() {

    }

    public FTPLogin(String hostaddress, int port, String name,
            String password) {

        this.hostaddress = hostaddress;
        this.port = port;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return hostaddress + ";" + port + ";" + name + ";" + password;
    }
}
```

Comment: You couldn't find commons-net ? That would be one of the first hits for a google search "java ftp".

Comment: Sry, i meant I could not find any classes INSIDE Apache-Commons-Net that fitted. I am not a native speaker...

Comment: Then you did not spend any time looking at the documentation. http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Standard, I prefer [ftp4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/)

Comment: This is indeed a nice library, especially regarding size. However when it comes to testing (which I do not use anyway), I think [ApacheCommons-Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) is superior. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class users
{
     String username;
     String password;
     String[][] accounts = {{"Karthik", "k123"},{"Ram", "r123"}};

     users(String user, String pass)
    {
        username = user;
        password = pass;
    }

     public boolean auth()
         {
        if((username == accounts[0][0]) && (password == accounts[0][1]))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if((username == accounts[1][0]) && (password == accounts[1][1]))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter name:");
            String s=sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter pid:");
            int i=sc.nextInt();
            users obj=new users(s,i);
            System.out.println(obj.auth());
        }
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit

Comment: i just took 3 private instance variables and a parameterised constructer and declared local variables in the constructer and i differentiated both instance and local variables with this keyword and took a return type method and i wrote logic if both username and password both are equal then my condition is true else false condition get executed and iam giving username and password from console for that reason i took scanner class

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Login
{
    public boolean checkValue(String name,String Password)
    {
        Hashtable<String,String> map=new Hashtable<String,String>();
        map.put(name,Password);
        //System.out.println(map);

            if(name.equals("abcd") && Password.equals("1234"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if(name.equals("Mnop") && Password.equals("5678"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if(name.equals("xyzx") && Password.equals("7890"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a name s:");
        String s=sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter a password p:");
        String p=sc.next();
        Login obj=new Login();
        boolean status=obj.checkValue(s,p);
        System.out.println(status);

    }
}
```

Comment: consider adding an explanation to your answer